# Python if statement is only executed once

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I try to make a simple spell checking programm by given two strings and adapt the first to the second one. If the strings have the same length my code works fine but if they're different, then the problems start. It only executes the if-statements once and stops after that. If I remove the break points, I get an IndexError: list index out of range.

Here is my code:

```
#!python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def edit_operations(first,second):

    a = list(first)
    b = list(second)
    counter = 0
    l_a = len(a)
    l_b = len(b)

    while True:
            if a == b:
                    break

            if l_a > l_b:
                    if a[counter] != b[counter]:
                            a[counter] = ""
                            c = "".join(a)
                            print "delete", counter+1, b[counter], c
                            counter += 1
                            l_a -= 1
                            break

            if l_a < l_b:
                    if a[counter] != b[counter]:
                            c = "".join(a)
                            c = c[:counter] + b[counter] + c[counter:]
                            print "insert", counter+1, b[counter], c
                            counter += 1
                            l_a += 1
                            break      

            if a[counter] != b[counter]:                       
                    a[counter] = b[counter]
                    c = "".join(a)
                    print "replace", counter+1, b[counter], c
                    counter += 1

            else:
                    counter += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    edit_operations("Reperatur","Reparatur")
    edit_operations("Singel","Single")
    edit_operations("Krach","Stall")
    edit_operations("wiederspiegeln","widerspiegeln")
    edit_operations("wiederspiglen","widerspiegeln")
    edit_operations("Babies","Babys")
    edit_operations("Babs","Babys")
    edit_operations("Babeeees","Babys")
```

This is the output I get:

```
replace 4 a Reparatur
replace 5 l Singll
replace 6 e Single
replace 1 S Srach
replace 2 t Stach
replace 4 l Stalh
replace 5 l Stall
delete 3 d widerspiegeln
replace 3 d widderspiglen
replace 4 e wideerspiglen
replace 5 r widerrspiglen
replace 6 s widersspiglen
replace 7 p widersppiglen
replace 8 i widerspiiglen
replace 9 e widerspieglen
replace 11 e widerspiegeen
replace 12 l widerspiegeln
delete 4 y Babes
insert 4 y Babys
delete 4 y Babeees
```

By the last 3 lines you can see my problem and I'm kinda desperate right now.
Hopefully someone could give me a hint what is wrong with it

Comment: So what is problem. We don't know what are you trying to do. Please update your post along with expected result.

Comment: You have `break` statements under the `if`s where the lengths are different; why would you expect the loop to continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title -- i.e., the if statement executed only once --  is already in a comment to your question, that is, there are two `break`s in the two `if` blocks `if l_a < l_b:` and `if l_a < l_b:`.
In general, `break` statement interrupts the closest loop that it finds, no matter how nested the block where [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) finds itself is.

However, other problems do appear in your code:

- the size of the list `a` is kept the same, however the same `counter` is used for iterating over the letters of the two strings. In case the length of the two strings are different, this problem leads eventually to the error `IndexError: list index out of range`, because the only condition that allows to exit the loop is when the two strings are the same. Also, when `l_a > l_b`, the same character of `b` that mismatched with `a` should be checked with the character next to the deleted one, however this does not happen because of the same `counter`.
- When `l_a < l_b` the list `a` is not modified; just a new list `c` is created with the additional letter. Please look at [`list` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).
- `counter` is not updated correctly, as, when the two strings differ in length, it is incremented only if the letters different. This leads to an infinite loop.

In general, consider using a debugger in order to figure out the issues (look at the debuggers available in python https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools). It is possible to find online or in a bookstore many resources to learn how to debug code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand now what I did wrong. And thank your for suggesting me that debugging tool, I was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the `list.insert()` function to insert a character into the list, the `del` operator to remove a single character from the list, and move the a==b comparison into the `while` loop conditional.  The variable `counter` should indicate the index of the next character to be compared, and should not be incremented if the characters are not equal.  Like this:

```
#! python3

def edit_operations(first,second):
    a = list(first)
    b = list(second)
    counter = 0

    while a != b:
        if a[counter] != b[counter]:
            if len(a) > len(b):
                print("delete", counter + 1, a[counter])
                del a[counter]
            elif len(b) > len(a):
                print("insert", counter + 1, b[counter])
                a.insert(counter, b[counter])
            else:
                print("replace", counter + 1, b[counter])
                a[counter] = b[counter]
        else:
            counter += 1
    print("".join(a))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    edit_operations("Reperatur","Reparatur")
    edit_operations("Singel","Single")
    edit_operations("Krach","Stall")
    edit_operations("wiederspiegeln","widerspiegeln")
    edit_operations("wiederspiglen","widerspiegeln")
    edit_operations("Babies","Babys")
    edit_operations("Babs","Babys")
    edit_operations("Babeeees","Babys")
```

I've changed the print statements a little.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I think I got it now.

Answer (score -5):

I really don't understand what your question is but if you need a spelling checker just use this [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/)

Comment: In what possible way is this an answer to the question?